# Stop the audio-player with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm making it short: I have a audio player (audio.js) which plays a song. But I want to make the audio pause when I click on a button above. This is what it looks like: (oh sorry, I dont have the permission to upload images) :D

"Hier die Musik ausschalten" is german and means "Stop playing".

This is my code:

```
<body>
<h1>Mein Audio-Test</h1>

<button class="noMusic">Hier die Musik ausschalten!</button>

    <!-----Der Audio-Player--->

<audio src="audio/Palace%20Cat%20-%20Crookshanks.mp3" preload="auto" />


    <!--------- Scripts für Audio --------------->
    <script src="audio/audiojs/audio.js"></script>
    <script>
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>


    <!----------- jquery ----------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <!-------- ----------- ------>
    <script>

    $( ".noMusic" ).click(function( event ) {

         var player = this.settings.createPlayer;
        container[audiojs].helpers.removeClass(this.wrapper, player.playingClass);


    });
        </script>

    </body>
```

I really dont know what I'm wrong. Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `audio.js` is for, but it's simple to hook into the browser audio API:

```
var $player = $('audio');

$('.noMusic').click(function (event) {
  $player.get(0).pause();
});
```